# Compiling OpenCV samples in Mac OS X 10.8.2

Tags: macos, opencv

I spent a good amount of time installing OpenCV on my Macbook running 10.8.2, and I was successful using the latest version of CMake and OpenCV 2.4.4.

However I can't find any straightforward methods on how to compile the FaceTracker.cpp file included in the /samples folder inside the opencv dir. I'm not so sure of how to link the necessary libs to compile and run it. Also tried opening the XCode proj included in the same folder to build it and it failed because it couldn't find any OpenCV.frameworks. Can you guys point me in the right direction on how to compile and run? And maybe how to use opencv framework with XCode?

I've searched on forums and Google and couldn't find anything that as similar to my issues and all the information I found was either outdated or too confusing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Download OpenCV 2.4.4 source code and inside the root directory execute the following commands:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ../
make
sudo make install
```

If that doesn't work, and assuming you have OpenCV installed on your system, **jump to the directory `samples/MacOSX/FaceTracker` and execute**:

```
g++ FaceTracker.cpp -o FaceTracker `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` -framework Cocoa
```

The above command will compile the application after you **edit the file `FaceTracker.cpp`** and replace all it's `#include` instructions by the following:

```
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
```

Comment: Thanks! I managed to compile using XCode by adding the libraries to the linker flags option. It was such a hassle to set up at first but I think I got it now.

Answer (score 0):

The FaceTracker example is outdated: OpenCV.framework does not exist anymore for the OpenCV 2.x.x series.
This sample was proposed at the time of OpenCV 1.1.

When you open the Xcode project, go to the build settings and search for the **other linker flags** option.
You can add here the required dynamic libraries (`-lopencv_legacy`and so on, without the dylib extension).
You may also have to modify the **linker search path** option to include the destination where OpenCV is installed (usually it is `/usr/local/bin`).